TCP connections to ISTIO Sidecar proxy not reaching service
Istio verison: v1.13
Kubernetes: v1.20.6
Goal:
Open A TCP connection from Service A to Service B and send data
Problem:
Service A starts, opens a connection to Service B (Matching the IP of the service B), but the connection is never received in Service B, but Service A says it has terminated.
We have just moved cluster, so I assume its some configuration as to how Istio handles TCP traffic.
So far I have tried:

PeerAuthentication - Set to both Permissive and Disable
Create a NodePort to hit the service directly

Only thing that worked was setting the
traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: 9696
Comparison to old and new
I've compared the old and new cluster (checking the pods for inject istio sidecar config)

istio.io/rev: default
- args:
    - --trust-domain=cluster.local
  env:
  - name: JWT_POLICY
      value: first-party-jwt
  - name: PROXY_CONFIG
      value: |
        {"proxyMetadata":{"DNS_AGENT":""}}

There are added in the new cluster istio side container.
  - emptyDir:
      medium: Memory
    name: istio-envoy
  - emptyDir: {}
    name: istio-data
  - downwardAPI:
      defaultMode: 420
      items:
      - fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.labels
        path: labels
      - fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.annotations
        path: annotations
    name: istio-podinfo
  - name: istio-token
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          audience: istio-ca
          expirationSeconds: 43200
          path: istio-token
  - configMap:
      defaultMode: 420
      name: istio-ca-root-cert
    name: istiod-ca-cert


Looks like the issue was related to the PeerAuthentication being defaulted to STRICT. When I DISABLE THE peer authentication is worked as expected.
